# Updating issue in child table using nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

In nhibernate i am having two tables parent and child...

**Parent-->** parentid,name

**Child -->** childid,name,parentid

**relation-->** one to many

If i insert a record in a parent table at the same time i will insert many records in the child table without any issue..

but if i update the parent record the child table records are not updating instead of that its inserting again..

Below is my mapping code

**Parent :**

```
HasMany(x => x.Child)
              .Not.LazyLoad()
              .Cascade.All();
```

**Child  :** `References(x => x.Parent).Not.LazyLoad();`

Comment: show us the code you're using to modify the parent record.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely the Id generator in childs used. SaveOrUpdate doesnt see them as persisted and tries to insert them. often `UnsavedValue("0")` can do the trick

Also it would be better to have inverse set to tell NH that the Childs are responsible for the association.

```
HasMany(x => x.Child)
      .Not.LazyLoad()
      .Inverse()
      .Cascade.All();

// eg: in Parent class
public void Add(Child child)
{
    Childs.Add(child);
    child.Parent = this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

Change the parent mapping file with the below code it will delete the old child data and insert new record in the child table

```
HasMany(x => x.Child)
              .Not.LazyLoad()              
              .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```